# Blue Prism text to PDF

Tags: pdf, text, blueprism, rpa

I would like to save the content of my text variable (text data item that stores information previously extracted from other source in the process flow) as a PDF document. Is there a way to save a text into PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the text to a new Word document using the `MS Word VBO`’s `Create Document` and `Write Text` actions, then use the same object’s `Save to PDF` action to write a PDF representation of the file to the file system.